# Phase of Dirac delta

Tags: education, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

How can I get the phase of the following Fourier transform:

$$X(f)=\frac 1 2 \delta\left(f-\frac B 2\right)+\frac 1 2 \delta\left(f+\frac B 2\right)+\frac 1 {2j} \delta\left(f-\frac {3B} 2\right)-\frac 1 {2j} \delta\left(f+\frac {3B} 2\right)$$

Maybe have I phase=$0$ at $f=\pm B/2$, phase=$-\pi /2$ at $f=3B/2$ and phase=$\pi /2$ at $f=-3B/2?$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in figure 3.27 at page 99 of the book "L. Verrazzani, G. Corsini - Teoria dei segnali" that the phase of the frequency components in which there are Dirac delta are equal to the phase of the coefficients that multiply the Dirac delta.

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful , you can express them in terms of sin and cosine , using duality property
$$1 \Leftrightarrow 2\pi \delta(\omega) \implies e^{j\omega_0 t} \Leftrightarrow 2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega_0) $$
Now if we use this , and break sin and cosine into exponential basis then we'll have 
$$\cos (\omega_0 t) \Leftrightarrow \pi \{\delta(\omega-\omega_0)+\delta(\omega+\omega_0)\}$$
$$\sin (\omega_0 t) \Leftrightarrow \frac{\pi}{2j} \{\delta(\omega-\omega_0)-\delta(\omega+\omega_0)\}$$
You can also write these in terms of $f$ then there wont a  $\pi$ for both cases.

Comment: Hi @Lelouch.D.Light, thus my answer is right?

Comment: yes it seems it's right with the very little knowledge i possess , i actually learnt them very recently form one of my brother's (he is a electrical engg student) book called signal and linear system analysis , so i'm still a little shaky , but it seems that your phase calculation is right !

Comment: I have the book "A.N. Tripathi - Linear system analysis, Revised 2nd Ed", but I don't find any example on it.

Comment: have you tried a book called alan v oppenheim , it's good.

Comment: I have that book. Examples of Fourier transform are without phase (when there are Dirac delta).

Comment: okay , sorry i don't have a lot of knowledge to help you further :(

Comment: Thank you anyway @Lelouch.D.Light.